# How to do page navigation from non-derived PhoneApplicationPage Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, navigation

I'm new to Windows phone 8 development. I'm trying to navigate from my AzureFunctions class to another page but I always get this error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have googled but still can't find any solution. Do you guys have any idea how to achieve this?

My RegisterPage (where I called InsertData method in AzureFunctions class)

```
private void signUp_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (email_validation && password_validation && confirmPassword_validation == true)
        {
            new AzureFunctions().InsertData(new UserInfo_Table_Azure()
            {
                Email = regisEmail_textBox.Text,
                Password = regisPassword_textBox.Password,
                DOB = (DateTime)DOB_picker.Value,
                UserCancerInfo = (Boolean)userCancerInfo_checkBox.IsChecked,
                FamilyCancerInfo = (Boolean)userFamilyCancerInfo_checkBox.IsChecked
            });
        }
        else
        {
            String errorMsg = "";
            if (email_validation == false)
            {
                errorMsg += "Your email is not valid\r\n";
                regisEmail_textBox.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
            if (password_validation == false)
            {
                errorMsg += "Your password can't be empty\r\n";
                regisPassword_textBox.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
            if (confirmPassword_validation == false)
            {
                errorMsg += "Your Confirm password and password aren't matched";
                comfirmPassword_textBox.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
            MessageBox.Show(errorMsg);
        }
    }
```

My AzureFunctions Class

```
public async void InsertData(object data)
    {
        try
        {
            SystemFunctions.SetProgressIndicatorProperties(true);
            SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Registering...";

            //Check type of data
            if (IsUserInfo_Data(data))
            {
                //Insert data into UserInfo_Table
                await azure_userInfo_table.InsertAsync((UserInfo_Table_Azure)data);
                Debug.WriteLine("Success inserting data to azure");
                SystemFunctions.SetProgressIndicatorProperties(false);

                MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(AppResources.RegisterSuccessfully, AppResources.Congratulation, MessageBoxButton.OK);
                if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        new RegisterPage().NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                    }
                    catch (NullReferenceException e)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (IsPoop_Data(data))
            {
                //Insert data into Poop_Table
                await azure_poop_table.InsertAsync((Poop_Table_Azure)data);
                Debug.WriteLine("Success");
            }

        }
        catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException e)
        {
            SystemFunctions.SetProgressIndicatorProperties(false);
            Debug.WriteLine("Failed: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really a good idea to do navigation from a non-Page, but this should work

```
App.RootFrame.Navigate(...)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Why I should not do it? does it cause memory leak or what?

Comment: more of a style problem, mixing business logic with navigation